# Nginx non-www not working and redirect in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have my server in DO running in Ubuntu 16.04.
My problem is that my site wont load when I try to run without *www*.

I followed the tutorial from here.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

My goal is to

1. redirect all non-www to https://example.com
2. redirect all www to https://www.example.com

*nginx/sites-available/nginx_config*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com http://example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com http://www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        root /home/tim/site.folder;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

What I have tried so far:

Removing **http** in *first and second server block*. (same in second server block)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your goal
 1. redirect all non-www to https://example.com 
 2. redirect all www to https://www.example.com
This can be done by

```
server_name www.example.com example.com;
```

You can use full configuration like following

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  access_log off;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  root /home/tim/site.folder;

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
 #fastcgi_pass remote_php_ip:9000;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-cgi.sock;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 include fastcgi.conf;
}
location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|flv|ico)$ {
 expires 30d;
 access_log off;
}
location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
 expires 7d;
 access_log off;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Gonna try this one.

Answer (score 0):

dont put http

```
 server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

 server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com;
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

 server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    root /home/tim/site.folder;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please see the updated question. I included what I have tried so far. Thanks for the resposne

Comment: which server block? I can't see http under any server_name.

Comment: sorry, i saw ur updated codes now. your server block should work now, may I know what is the error u receive now? Infinite loop? 500 error? 404 error? are u using php?

Comment: It just says "This site can’t be reached". Yes, PHP

Comment: Did you do a sudo service Nginx reload? If you have follow the entire DO tutorial step by step without missing any. It will work 100%.